# How to compare password with the password which is encrypted and stored in DB, when user enters for login

Tags: java

If a user register for first time, then all his credential are saved in DB and password is in encrypted form. Now I have module in which user again has to enter his credential to login to my module. What will be the code to compare that password on database (encrypted form) to login successfully.

Other team is developing the full application in .net technology and stored the password using SHA2 hashing algorithm. But my module is developing in Java Servlet. Once our module is completed they will call the page. What will be the full code for this to login successfully for my module? How do I can successful login from my Java code comparing there password stored in database.

Comment: Do you have the decoding method ?

Comment: SHA2 is not an encryption method, it is an hash and you should have API in Java that let you have the SHA2 of a string. Once you have that you could compare the 2 SHA2 strings.

Comment: normally you dont decode, but instead encode the user input and compare it against the stored in Db....

Comment: You need to store your password in hashed and salted format, not encrypted. It should not be reversible. When a plaintext hash is presented to you, hash it in the same way and you should either get the same hash as the database (password correct) or a different one (password wrong).

Comment: I have downvoted for the urgent begging and for the request for "full code". We do not do other people's work for them, and certainly not to a demanding timeframe. Please treat the time of volunteers with respect.

Comment: @MarioSantini Actually, [SHA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) is not even a hash method. It is a *set* of 6 hash methods: SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512, SHA-512/224, SHA-512/256. You'd have to specify exactly which one of these you're using, for it to work correctly.

Comment: @Andreas correct, but the OP was confusing it with encryption, so my point was it's not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you hash the password provided by the user with SHA-2 the resulting string must be equal to a string from the DB in case the password is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload the code that you tried.However, if you just want to verify hashed password from mysql database try below link,Hope it works

[Verifying Hashed Password From MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168568/verifying-hashed-password-from-mysql-database)